# No difference between font-size x-large and xx-large in Firefox 78.7.1esr

Tags: css, firefox

I wonder why there is no difference between `x-large` and `xx-large` in Firefox 78.7.1esr.

```css
p {
  font-family: BlinkMacSystemFont,-apple-system,"Segoe UI",Roboto,Oxygen,Ubuntu,Cantarell,"Fira Sans","Droid Sans","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<p style="font-size: large">large</p>
<p style="font-size: x-large">x-large</p>
<p style="font-size: xx-large">xx-large</p>
<p style="font-size: xxx-large">xxx-large</p>
```

My view:
[image]
Can someone confirm that behaviour?

Comment: Wich version of firefox do you run ? cause mine(latest) makes the difference.  screenshot : https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJl6n.jpg

Comment: @G-Cyrillus: "Firefox 78.7.1esr" but I don't see why it wouldn't work there either. xx-large isn't a new value.

Comment: Really strange. See the screenshot in the updated question.

Comment: that's a portable version, right ?

Comment: @G-Cyrillus: No, ESR stands for Extended Support Release, generally used in the enterprise with slow release cycles.

Comment: No. Not portable.

Comment: okay, i got confused from : https://portableapps.com/news/2021-02-05--firefox-portable-esr-78.7.1-released (i was once using a portable version on a usb key and gave up after a few updates ;) )

Comment: I guess it's a bug in Firefox 78.7.1esr. It works in Firefox 85.0.2.